# JavaScript ground work for creating a bubble game

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need help with Javascript fundamentals the issue I am having is with my start button when it clicks on it supposed to create a prompt that asks the user for the first name and have it stored within that variable you created. I have the doc ready function working okay however the button is not working properly.

Here is my code and thank you  for helping me

```html
<!-- Name: <Put name here> Date: <Put date here> Class: CSCI2447, Javascript Fundamentals Project X \-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>POP-The- Bubble (CSCI2447)</title>

<!-- CSS styles: This is for me to worry about; not you. -->

<link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sunshiney&display=swap](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sunshiney&display=swap)" rel="stylesheet">

<script src = "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"> </script>

<script> $( document ).ready(function() { var first Name = prompt("Enter First Name of Gamer:"); </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">

<h1>Pop-The-Bubble</h1>

<p>After clicking "start", you will have 30 seconds to click

on as many bubbles as you can. The bubbles will appear quickley so be ready!

</p>

<div id="controls">

<span id="score">0 pts</span>

<button type="button" id="start\_button">Start!</button>

</div>

<div id="gamespace">

<img class="gameimage" src="img/bubblefun2.png" height = "120" width = "120"

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have not close `$(document).ready(function() { ` .. i.e  : `})` .Also , remove space between `first Name` .

Comment: Okay thank you I will go try it out right now and I might need more help later

Answer (score 0):

Your function should close with the closing curly braces `}`  and bracket `)` => `})`

`$( document ).ready(function() { var firstName = prompt("Enter First Name of Gamer:") });`

Also you have a space between first and Name, this will throw an error in javascript `Unexpected identifier`. Remove the space so it is one string as the variable name `firstName`